# Providing Edgar emission using prep_chem_source for tracers (CO2-CH4)

Tags: meteorology, climate-change, climate-models, wrf, wrf-chem

I am working on CO<sub>2</sub> and CH<sub>4</sub> by WRF-CHEM, for providing my anthropogenic emission from Edgar data base, I'm going to use the Prep_chem_source App.

I would like to use Edgar data emission (as my anthropogenic emission) for CO<sub>2</sub>-CH<sub>4</sub> and simulate these gasses by WRF-CHEM.
due to the Prep_chem_source instruction, I have done bellow steps:

1. I consider chem_opt=0 and run the `./real.exe`
2. Run `./prep_chem_source.exe`
3. Link the output of files of step 2, to my em_real
   directory (emissopt3_d01,...)
4. Change namelist.input  chem_opt in to 17, chem_opt=17
5. Run `./convert_emiss.exe`

But `./convert` doesn't make wrfchemi_d01 ,wrffirechemi_d02,...
what shall I do to have E_CO2, E_CH4,...as my anthropogenic emission from Edgar, using prep_source?

It is a part of my name list:

```
&time_control
run_days                 = 0,
run_hours                = 30,
run_minutes              = 0,
run_seconds              = 0,
start_year               = 2007, 2007,
start_month              = 08, 08,
start_day                = 1,  1,
start_hour               = 18,       18,
start_minute             = 00,       00,
start_second             = 00,       00,
end_year                 = 2010, 2010,
end_month                = 08, 08,
end_day                  = 03, 03,
end_hour                 = 00,      00,
end_minute               = 00,       00,
end_second               = 00,       00,
input_from_file          = .true.,   .true.,
interval_seconds         = 21600,
history_outname          = "wrfout<domain>_<date>",
frames_per_auxinput5     = 2,    2,
auxinput5_inname         = "wrfchemi_d<domain>_<date>",
auxinput5_interval_m     = 1440,  1440,
io_form_auxinput5        = 2,
frames_per_auxinput7     = 2,    2,
auxinput7_inname         = "wrffirechemi_d<domain>_<date>",
auxinput7_interval_m     = 1440,  1440,
io_form_auxinput7        = 2,
history_interval         = 60,      60,
frames_per_outfile       = 1000,     1000,
restart                  = .false.,
write_hist_at_0h_rst     = .true.,
restart_interval         = 360,
io_form_history          = 2,
io_form_restart          = 2,
io_form_input            = 2,
io_form_boundary         = 2,
debug_level              = 0,
/
&physics
mp_physics               = 10,        10,  ! 3,        3,
ra_lw_physics            = 1,        1,
ra_sw_physics            = 1,        1,
radt                     = 30,       2,
sf_sfclay_physics        = 1,        1,
sf_surface_physics       = 2,        2,
bl_pbl_physics           = 8,        8,  ! 1,        1,
bldt                     = 0,        0,
cu_physics               = 3,        3,  ! 3,        3,
cudt                     = 0,        0,  ! 5,        5,
isfflx                   = 1,
ifsnow                   = 1,
icloud                   = 1,
surface_input_source     = 1,
num_soil_layers          = 4,
! sf_urban_physics       = 0,    0,
cu_diag                  = 1,  1,
cugd_avedx               = 1,    !  3,
cu_rad_feedback          = .true.,   .true.,
maxiens                  = 1,
maxens                   = 3,
maxens2                  = 3,
maxens3                  = 16,
ensdim                   = 144,
/

&chem
 chem_opt                            = 17,  17,
 vertmix_onoff                       = 1,  1,
 have_bcs_chem                       = .true., .true.,
!! have_bcs_tracer                     = .false., .false.,
 chem_in_opt                         = 0,  0,
 term_opt                            = "CH4_termite_OW", "CH4_termite_OW",
 emiss_inpt_opt                      = 16,  16,
 emiss_opt                           = 17, 17,
 chem_conv_tr  
! bb_opt_ghg                          = 0, 0,
 biomass_burn_opt                    = 5,   5, ! 0,  0,
 !plumerisefire_frq                   = 60, 60,
 io_style_emissions                  = 2,
 kemit                               = 1,
 bioemdt                             = 30, 30,
 photdt                              = 30,  30,
 chemdt                              = 1.,  1.,
 phot_opt                            = 0,   0,
 bio_emiss_opt                       = 1,   1,
 conv_tr_wetscav                     = 0,   0,
 gas_bc_opt                          = 0,   0,
 gas_ic_opt                          = 0,   0,
 aer_bc_opt                          = 0,   0,
 aer_ic_opt                          = 0,   0,
 gaschem_onoff                       = 0,   0,
 aerchem_onoff                       = 0,   0,
 wetscav_onoff                       = 0,   0,
 cldchem_onoff                       = 0,   0,
 aer_ra_feedback                     = 0,   0,
 vprm_opt                            = "VPRM_table_TROPICS", "VPRM_table_TROPICS",
 gas_drydep_opt                      = 0,   0,
/
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages? I am not familiar with the emission preprocessing routines of WRF. Therefore, I am guessing a bit (since no one else commented yet): Which version of the EDGAR emissions are you using? Which namelist file did you modify? According to [this talk](https://ruc.noaa.gov/wrf/wrf-chem/wrf_tutorial_nepal/talks/Emissions.pdf) one needs to modify the namelists in `prep_chem_sources.inp` (e.g. slide 19: add option `use_edgar`). Not sure, if this presentation refers to the version of WRF that you are using.

Comment: hi dear daniel.heydebreck, thanks for the response. I didn't get any error. the prep_chem_source  doesn't make any emission file(wrfchemi,wrffirechemi,...).I am working with wrf.3.9.1.1.in addition i use _edgar ( use_edgar =3,  ! 0 - not,! 1 - Version 3,    ! 2 - Version 4 for some species  ! 3 - Version HTAP),2 and 3. you know? I need to have E_CO2 and E_CH4 as my anthropogenic emission from Edgar.I have chosen (chem_opt=16 or 17)(the greenhouse gases chemistry option in user guide of wrf-chem). I don't know how can I have anthropogenic emission for CO2 and CH4?

Comment: Which EDGAR data did you download? The EDGAR-HTAP dataset should only contain air pollutants (and no greenhouse gases). Could you provide an URL? Did you download the netCDF or txt data?

Comment: I am working on the almost the middle east and the prep_chem source uses the data of Global emission version 3.it has (EDGAR-HTAP, Edgar,...(ftp://aftp.fsl.noaa.gov/divisions/taq/global_emissions) they are all old and are for 2005.txt and it has not any unit!). but in the Edgar web site, it has EDGAR emission V5(in 2 formats of txt(ton) and NetCDF(kg/m2s). what shall I do to make anthropogenic emission?(hourly)?prep_chem_source? by which name list? I would like to have E_CO2 and E_CH4? thank you ...

Comment: If I download the `global_emissions_v3_24aug2015.tar.gz` from the FTP Server, then I find three folders with EDGAR emission datasets in it: `EDGAR`, `EDGAR-HTAP` and `EDGARV4`. The first and third folder contain emissions for greenhouse gases in `txt` format. Probably `EDGAR` contains verion 3 EDGAR emissions. The second folder contains emissions of air pollutants in `h5` format (HDF5). ...

Comment: If I download the `prep_chem_sources_v1.5_24aug2015.tar.gz` from the FTP Server, then I find `bin/prep_chem_sources.inp`. Now, you need to modify the variables `use_edgar` and `edgar_data_dir`. If you want to process the emission data from the `EDGAR` directory, you need to set `use_edgar=1` and `edgar_data_dir` to the proper path. If you want to process data from the `EDGARV4` directory, you need to set `use_edgar=2`. If you want to process data from the `EDGAR-HTAP` directory, you need to set `use_edgar=3`.

Comment: If this does not help you: What happens if you set some clearly bad values in the `prep_chem_sources.inp` file? On which operating system are you working and which compiler did you use to compile your preprocessor routines?

Comment: yes, I use "prep_chem_sources_v1.5_24aug2015.tar.gz" , you are right, I have done the things you say(" you need to set use_edgar=1 and edgar_data_dir to the proper path. If you want to process data from the,..."), and I tested both (use_edgar=1 and 3) and changed the path of the directory, and the prep has been compiled success.

Comment: but when I link the matrix _..ab,bb, gocart.into my WRFV3/test/em_real folder and use the chem_opt=17and run the ./convert_emiss.exe,it doesn't make wrfchemi_d01,wrffirechemi_d01,....and if I change the chem_opt to aerosol option like 106,301, it makes wrfchemi,...but it haven't E_co2, and E_CH4 in wrfchemi_d01,.... in the wrfchemi_d01.you know? I think my name list has a problem with choosing (chem_opt =17). but this option is the only option(chem_opt option I mean) for CO2 and CH4. I have not any other option to choose instead of 17 or 16 in wrf-chem3.9.1.1 user guide.

Comment: Hm. No idea. Good luck.

Comment: thank you in advance, Dear daniel